# No me toma los datos el Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2005, sqldatatypes

Estoy realizando mi tesis y estoy teniendo problema con mi código de SQL:

El primero es es que quiero crear una tabla de esta forma y no me deja:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[EDetalles_Compras] AS TABLE(    
[IdProducto] int NULL,    
[PrecioCompra] decimal (18,2) NULL,    
[PrecioVenta] decimal (18,2) NULL,    
[Cantidad] int NULL,    
[SubTotal] decimal (18,2) NULL    
)
```

Me sale este error:

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de la palabra clave 'AS'.
```

El segundo problema es que quiero realizar un procedimiento y tampoco me deja y la tabla con la que lo quiero relacionarla esta bien creada. El código es el siguiente:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_RegistrarCompra(    
@IdUsuario int,    
@IdProveedor int,    
@TipoDocumento varchar (500),    
@NumeroDocumento varchar(500),    
@SubTotal decimal (18,2),    
@DetalleCompra [EDetalle_Compra] READONLY,    
@Resultado bit output,    
@Mensaje varchar(500) output    
)    
as    
begin    
    begin try    
    declare @idcompra int = 0    
    set @Resultado = 1    
    set @Mensaje = ''    

    begin transaction registro

    insert into COMPRA (IdUsuario, IdProveedor, TipoDocumento, NumeroDocumento, SubTotal)
    values (@IdUsuario, @IdProveedor, @TipoDocumento, @NumeroDocumento, @SubTotal)

    set @idcompra = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    insert into DETALLE_COMPRA (IdCompra, IdProducto, PrecioCompra, PrecioVenta, Cantidad, SubTotal)
    select @idcompra, IdProducto, PrecioCompra, PrecioVenta, Cantidad, SubTotal from @DetalleCompra

    update p set p.Stock = p.Stock + dc.Cantidad,
    p.PrecioCompra = dc.PrecioCompra,
    p.PrecioVenta = dc.PrecioVenta
    from PRODUCTO p
    inner join @DetalleCompra dc on dc.IdProducto = p.IdProducto

    commit transaction registro
    end try

    begin catch
        set @Resultado = 0
        set @Mensaje = ERROR_MESSAGE()

        rollback transaction registro
    end catch
end
```

y los errores que me marcan son estos:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 7 [Batch Start Line 1]
Sintaxis incorrecta cerca de 'READONLY'.
Msg 139, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 1]
No se puede asignar un valor predeterminado a una variable local.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 15 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@Resultado".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 16 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@Mensaje".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 23 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@idcompra".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 26 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@idcompra".
Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 32 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable de tabla "@DetalleCompra".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 38 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@Resultado".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure SP_RegistrarCompra, Line 39 [Batch Start Line 1]
Debe declarar la variable escalar "@Mensaje".
```

Lo pase por el chat GPT pero me dice que el código esta bien hecho y no encuentra lo que esta mal. Alguien me podría ayudar y decir en que me estoy confundiendo?

Muchas gracias

Esto es lo que me tira cuando pongo:

```
SELECT compatibility_level, @@VERSION 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE database_id = DB_ID()
```

[image]

Comment: 3 cosas: 1. Bienvenida. 2. Revisa https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y obtengas tu primera medalla. 3. `@DetalleCompra [EDetalle_Compra] READONLY`  ¿a qué te refieres con esta línea?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el resultado de la siguiente consulta?  `SELECT compatibility_level, @@VERSION FROM sys.databases WHERE database_id = DB_ID()` . Me parece que es un problema de versiones.

Comment: Veo que perdiste uno de los dos usuarios.. ahora pido que te fusionen las cuentas...

Answer (score 1):

Tu problema es que estás usando una versión obsoleta de hace 18 años. Por cuestiones de seguridad y funcionalidad, es mejor usar versiones recientes que siguen recibiendo soporte por parte de Microsoft.

El código es correcto y funcionará a partir de la versión 2008. Sin embargo, como es un proyecto escolar, lo más recomendable es usar la última versión disponible que por ahora es la 2022. Para ambientes productivos reales, es importante que la migración tenga bastantes pruebas para comprobar que el funcionamiento es correcto.

Puedes descargar las últimas versiones desde la página oficial donde tienen un par de opciones gratuitas. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads

Answer (score -1):

Para crear tablas, según la documentación oficial:

```
CREATE TABLE
    { database_name.schema_name.table_name | schema_name.table_name | table_name }
    ( { <column_definition> } [ ,... n ] )
[ ; ]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Aquí un ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    LastName varchar(255),
    FirstName varchar(255),
    Address varchar(255),
    City varchar(255)
);
```

Ejemplo extraído de: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp

Para la creación de Store Procedures:

```
USE AdventureWorks2022;  
GO  
CREATE PROCEDURE HumanResources.uspGetEmployeesTest2   
    @LastName nvarchar(50),   
    @FirstName nvarchar(50)   
AS   

    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
    SELECT FirstName, LastName, Department  
    FROM HumanResources.vEmployeeDepartmentHistory  
    WHERE FirstName = @FirstName AND LastName = @LastName  
    AND EndDate IS NULL;  
GO
```

Ejemplo extraído de: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: No está creando una tabla. Está creando un tipo definido por usuario tipo tabla para después usarlo como parámetro. Tus ejemplos son correctos, pero no se aplican al problema de la pregunta.

Comment: Eso sí lo sé de antemano, el usuario está muy confundido, así que tuve que poner ejemplos desde lo más básico para que vea y compare los ejemplos con su código actual. Así que los negativos, es lo de menos.